# Why does sound stop working after a while?

Tags: 10.10, sound, troubleshooting

I don't know how to reproduce this problem, because I don't regularly play music or sound. All I know is that, sometimes, I'll load a video (from youtube or from a local file) and there will be no sound.

Everything looks fine software wise:

- Rebooting *always* fixes.
- `aplay`, `paplay` and pals give no error message
- I'm not in the `audio` group, [as advised](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/TheAudioGroup)
- The device exists and appears in use:

  ```
  $ lsof /dev/snd/by-path/pci-0000\:00\:1b.0
  COMMAND     PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
  pulseaudi 17313 badp   23u   CHR 116,10      0t0 7628 /dev/snd/by-path/../controlC0
  pulseaudi 17313 badp   30u   CHR 116,10      0t0 7628 /dev/snd/by-path/../controlC0
  ```
- Restarting pulseaudio or alsa seems to do no good.

What is wrong here?

Comment: If you are using gnome, you can get to sound preferences from the audio icon.  This will show you what applications are trying to do things.   Sometimes I've had browsers produce many entries - possibly many tabs with sound events.   That caused temporary sound issues for me.

Comment: @jgbelacqua No, that tab is usually empty.

Comment: Can you tell us what version/architecture Ubuntu you're using ? (e.g., on straight Ubuntu 10.10, 64-bit, I fortunately haven't seen this issue....).  Also, have you modified any packages that could have possibly touched sound drivers or changed default pulseaudio behavior?  Finally, what kind of uptime and what kind of apps do you have running when this happens (or what apps have you had running prior to the failure you notice)?  Thanks.

Comment: @jgbelacqua: Ubuntu 10.10 32 bit with PPAs/software sources for/from Chromium, Google, GetDeb, Dropbox, Gnome Shell, Unity, Skype, Firefox, Ground Control, Transmission, GMail, Miro, Medibuntu, Gwibber, Nouveau, Opera, George's SE notification thingadongdong, Mumble, X, MeTv, Banshee, Aubergine, Ubuntu Tweak, Wine, ... a large list, but nothing sound related  that I use. (I don't have software installed from them all). Uptime can be a few hours. Usually, it's just a browser and/or VLC and/or Flash.

Answer (score 4):

An interesting tool I hadn't seen from 
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingSoundProblems :

`ubuntu-bug audio`

It attempts to do some interactive checks.  If you haven 't, try running that when the issue occurs.  But the checks are worth running any time.   I believe the bug information generated will provide the information that the next links ask for.  (For example, giving the equivalent of the `alsa-info.sh` from fedora.  EDIT:  Actually, you can find alsa-info.sh [here](http://git.alsa-project.org/?p=alsa-driver.git;a=blob_plain;f=utils/alsa-info.sh).)

That page has some other good info as well.  I think most of the fixes are for constant problems, though, not intermittent ones like you are having.

Two Fedora-Linux wikis have some troubleshooting tips that could be extracted:
https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Bug_info_kernel_sound
https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Bug_info_PulseAudio

From the fedora pages:

> The output of `pulseaudio -vvvvv`, run
>   on the command line, is often helpful.
>   To provide this correctly, first
>   configure PulseAudio not to respawn
>   itself automatically when it dies, by
>   creating a file `~/.pulse/client.conf`
>   with this content:
>
> ```
> autospawn = no
> ```
>
> Then kill the existing server, with
>   the command `pulseaudio -k`. Now
>   launch `pulseaudio -vvvvv` from a
>   console, and reproduce your problem.
>   Provide the whole set of messages from
>   the console where you ran pulseaudio.
>
> The output of `pacmd ls` can also
>   provide a snapshot of the audio
>   system's state.

Application-wise, here's [a post](http://thomas.apestaart.org/log/?p=1012) (from 2009) mentioning that Skype caused problems for him:

> [...] I ran
>   into some problems with skype (bug
>   filed). PulseAudio asserts and goes
>   away probably because of something
>   Skype does wrong (although one could
>   argue that PulseAudio shouldn’t break
>   down completely because of one bad
>   client).

Of course, there are lot of possible culprits, but knowing that one of your apps has in the past caused problems is at least encouraging (or discouraging, if you want).

Long shot -- check your CPU time for the pulseaudio process -- noticed this from the manpage:

```
--no-cpu-limit[=BOOL]
```

> Do not install CPU load limiter on platforms that support it. By default, PulseAudio will terminate itself when
>   it notices that it takes up too much
>   CPU time. This is useful as a
>   protection against system lockups when
>   real-time scheduling is used [....]

Comment: I tried `ubuntu-bug audio`, no luck. The rest will get some attention later.

Answer (score 0):

Rebooting helping and restarting alsa and pulseaudio may indicate your sound drivers.

Try to reload sound driver if it is not working.

(If you do not know what is your driver paste here output of lsmod, and name of your sound card)

Comment: How do you reload the sound driver? Thanks.

Comment: give me name of your driver... but rmmod to unload, and insmod to load kernel module.

Comment: Except you can't unload a module in use...